# No WiFi Option & Network Unclaimed Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, 21.04

My network adapter is listed below.  I have tried for two days to resolve the issue of having no WiFi option unsuccessfully.  I even upgraded from 20.04 to 21.04.  There were a couple of times that the WiFi adapter was listed in the Additional Drivers tab of the Update Manager GUI, but it has since disappeared.  This issue began when I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, which I find funny since the computer was connected to the internet via WiFi for the entire install.

```
root@Skynet:~# lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
```

I hopefully can just use my USB to revert back to 18.04 but if there is a way to fix this and keep the updated version I would prefer to do that.

Comment: This adapter doesn't require any additional drivers. Thy with a LiveUSB.

Comment: Humor: Putting [Skynet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skynet_(Terminator)) on the internet has never ended well for humans.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by installing from a USB.  Directly installing from the software updater did not give me the option to install third party drivers, which was the issue.